# How to update user interface control programmatically?

Tags: c#, webforms, xmpp

Currently I am working on client server application using `xmpp` framework, following is the architecture I follow in my application.

Application layer i.e web client (web forms) will communicate with API layer and then the API layer will communicate with the `xmpp`framework. I want to update my user interface when a message from a friend is received. How can I update my user interface?

API layer contains the following code

```
 _xmppClientConnection.OnMessage += new agsXMPP.protocol.client.MessageHandler(XmppCon_OnMessage);
```

When someone messages me, this code executes and the message is caught in the code.

```
public void  XmppCon_OnMessage(object sender, agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message messsage)
{
    _xmppClientMessage= messsage;
}
```

I want to show this message on a control like text box which is another layer called user interface (web forms).

How can I update my UI when I receive a message at the API layer?

Application layer has a function

```
public void IncomingMessage(agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message message)
{
    txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text + message.Body;
}
```

How can I update UI, when a message is received at the API layer?

Answer (score 1):

you need a realtime channel like SignalR between you backend and frontend.
See also the post I wrote some years ago here:

http://www.ag-software.net/2012/08/20/web-clients-with-matrix-and-signalr/